# Why hyperlinks in MS Team bot stopped working?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We use FAQPlus and add markdown hyperlinks in the answer text.  These hyperlinks stopped working in the bot chat cards in both browser and desktop several weeks ago.  When I click the hyperlink noting happens.  The expected result is to open the link in a browser window

When I inspect the hyperlink in the Chromium console, it is a normal html anchor and the href is correct and target is _blank as expected.  I did notice several document level event listeners attached to the click event of the anchor.   One appears to be cancelling the click event and when I delete the event listener in Chromium console, the hyperlink works as expected.  The event lister is associated to this code and I see it goes to the finally block when I click the link.  Does anyone know what is causing this issue or how I can find more information about this event lister?

```
    function Yt(e, t, n, r) { 

        j || F(); 

        var i = Jt 

          , o = j; 

        j = !0; 

        try { 

            D(i, e, t, n, r) 

        } finally { 

            (j = o) || B() 

        } 

    }
```

Comment: Could you please  provide more details or the card JSON or the markdown hyperlink text 
 which you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AdaptiveCard text markdown 'bold' and 'hyperlink' causes hyperlink to be unclickable

```
{
   "type": "TextBlock",
   "wrap": true,
   "text": "[**Search**](https://www.bing.com)"
 }
```

It renders like a bold link, but clicking on it does not navigate to the link target.

However if you will use below syntax it works:

```
{
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "wrap": true,
      "text": "**[Search](https://www.bing.com)**"
    }
```

[image]

Sample JSON

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is some **bold** text"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is some _italic_ text"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "- Bullet \r- List \r",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "1. Numbered\r2. List\r",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Check out [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io)"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "wrap": true,
          "text": "This [**Search doesnt work**](https://www.bing.com)"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "wrap": true,
          "text": "This **[Search Works](https://www.bing.com)**"
        }
    ]
}
```